Proving $A:=\{x\in C(\bar{D}):x$ is analytic on $D\}$ a Banach Space
I was solving some exercises on proving Banach Space. A question is given in the following way:

Let $D$ denote the open unit disk in $\mathbf{C}$. Let $A:=\{x\in C(\bar{D}):x$ is analytic on $D\}$. For $x\in A$, let $\Vert x \Vert = max\{|x(e^{it})|:t\in [-\pi, \pi]\}$. Then, $A$ is a Banach Space in the norm $\Vert \bullet \Vert.$

Here, after proving the space normed linear, for showing it Banach, I, at first, take an absolutely summable sequence $\{x_n\}_n\in A$, which converges, that means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Vert x_n \Vert<\infty.$ Now, I want to prove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ converges in $A$. Let $z\in \bar{D}$, then $|x_n(z)|\le \Vert x_n \Vert, \forall z\in \bar{D}.$ Thus, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n(z)|<\infty$ in Banach space $\mathbf{C}.$ So, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n(z)<\infty$ and I denote $x(z):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n(z).$Then, $\Vert x -\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\Vert\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\Vert x_k\Vert\to0$, so, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ converges to $x$.
Now we have to show: $x$ is analytic on $D$. Here $\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence of analytic functions that converges uniformly on all compact subsets of domain $D$. By Morera's Theorem, $x$ is analytic on $D$.
Is my proof correct? If not, please help me to make it correct. Thank you, beforehand.

The overall structure looks good. However, I have a few suggestions since some parts really need some more detail or clarity.
The first is where you state that $|x_{n}(z)| \leq \|x_{n}\|$ for all $z\in \overline{D}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is equivalent to stating that
\begin{equation}
\sup \{|x_{n}(z)| : z\in \overline{D} \} \leq \sup \{|x_{n}(z)| : z\in \mathbb{C} \; \text{and} \; |z| = 1\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is not immediately clear since the supremum of the left-hand side of ($1$) is being taken over a strictly larger set than the right-hand side. And in fact ($1$) is false in general for continuous functions on $\overline{D}$. This is where you need that each $x_{n}$ is analytic on $D$ to apply a result such as the maximum modulus principle, so you should explicitly state this step.
The second is where, after defining $x$, you state that
\begin{equation}
\Big\|x - \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}\Big\| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \|x_{k}\| \to 0 .
\end{equation}
I would suggest this is too quick. Instead, you can do the following. Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $z\in \overline{D}$. Then for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m > n$ we have
\begin{equation}
\Big|\sum_{k=1}^{m}x_{k}(z) - \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}(z) \Big| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} |x_{k}(z)| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \|x_{k}\| .
\end{equation}
By taking the limit it follows that
\begin{equation}
\Big|x(z) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}(z) \Big| = \lim_{m\to\infty} \Big|\sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k}(z) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}(z) \Big| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \|x_{k}\|
\end{equation}
for each $z\in \overline{D}$. Hence we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sup \Big\{\Big|x(z) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}(z)\Big| : z\in \overline{D} \Big\} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \|x_{k}\| \tag{2}
\end{equation}
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that I am not using the norm expression on the left-hand side of ($2$) because the norm is only defined on $A$ and it hasn't yet been shown that $x\in A$. From here it does not take much work to deduce that
\begin{equation}
\sup\{|x(z)| : z\in \mathbb{C} \; \text{and} \; |z| = 1\} < \infty . \tag{3}
\end{equation}
For the last part regarding why the limit function is analytic, you should be looking at the sequence of partial sums since those are the ones which should be converging to $x$ uniformly on compact subsets. You should also be a bit more clear about why the limit is uniform on compact subsets of $D$. For example, you can use ($2$) to see that this happens. After that you can conclude from an argument involving Morera's theorem (or directly as a corollary of it) that the limit function is analytic on $D$. Now you can combine this with ($2$) and ($3$) to conclude that $x\in A$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} = x$ in $A$.
Note that if you are interested a shorter way to prove this, you can use that the norm $\| \bullet \|$ coincides with the supremum norm over $\overline{D}$ on $A$ by the maximum modulus principle. As a result, you can directly use that $C(\overline{D})$ is a Banach space to obtain that the limit function of your series is continuous on $\overline{D}$. Then you can apply an argument involving Morera's theorem to obtain the result.

Thank you so much!!! It helps a lot ...

That's great to hear that it helped!
